# Create asterisk with CSS. Asterisk is in new row not in the same one

Tags: html, css

I want to create asterisk with CSS

This is my code:

```
<div class="controls required">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" aria-live="polite" role="status">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
<input type="text></input>
<p class="help-block" id="school-description">TEXT</p>
<div>
```

and CSS SELECTOR `:after`

```
.required:after {
    content: "*";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

and now looks like

[image]

If I remove this part of code after input

```
<p class="help-block" id="school-description">TEXT</p>
```

then looks ok

[image]

what can I do? How to ignore description TEXT and put asterisk like in picture 2?

Comment: @Vucko - `<input>` can't have children :( so no pseudo elements either.

Comment: It's because you're a `<p>` tag, which is a block element. Try using a `<span>` and everything will be alright.

Comment: here is a wierd workaround without changing the HTML structure but I guess it would work : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/r6943z8k/

Comment: @misterManSam well, you learn something new everyday :)

Comment: Wrap the input in a `<label>` and place the after pseudo element on that label. Like [this example](http://jsbin.com/liqika/1/edit). If it needs a label that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your HTML like this, with an extra element around the input. That is because you cannot have an `:after` pseudo-element for inputs.

```
<div class="controls required">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" aria-live="polite" role="status">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
<span class="input-container"><input type="text></input></span>
<p class="help-block" id="school-description">TEXT</p>
<div>
```

Then, in your CSS change `.required:after {` to `.required .input-container:after {`.

Comment: +1 you beat me to it. I'd rather go with [`<label>`](http://jsbin.com/guzako/1/edit).

Comment: @HashemQolami You mean a label for `TEXT`? I completely agree with that, but I wanted to focus on the actual issue. For the `input-container` itself there arguably is added value for making it a label. I didn't since it doesn't contain text apart from the asterisk. It's only an extra aid to be able to style it, which is unfortunate enough as it is, since a CSS-only solution would be better, but if you look at it from another angle, it makes sense to make it a label.

Comment: @GolezTrol - doesn't it have a label? In the screenshot anyway "Ime šole".

Comment: Yes I mean use it to wrap the text (which is shown in the posted image) and the input element. I didn't add the text in the demo though.

Comment: @misterManSam You're right about the screenshot although I don't see it in the HTML. If that label is there, and it contains the input (which isn't always the case), then you can use that label.

Answer (score 0):

the "required" class is on the containing div, maybe try moving the "required" class to the input?

```
<div class="controls">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" aria-live="polite" role="status">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
<input type="text" class="required"></input>
<p class="help-block" id="school-description">TEXT</p>
<div>
```